# Dynamic Links Firebase function not being called at all Xcode 12?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui, firebase-dynamic-links

So I have a dynamic link that is working in that it opens up the app when I click on it but the handling of the dynamic link doesn't happen. This is because application function seen below is never entered and I'm not sure why...

```
func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink){
    guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
        print("That's weird. My dynamic link object has no url")
        return
    }
    print("Your incoming link parameter is \(url.absoluteString)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
        print("Incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
        let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
            guard error == nil else{
                print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            }
        }
        if linkHandled {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated--is it possible this is a problem with Firebase itself or no?

Comment: Do you use Xcode 12/ SwiftUI 2.0?

Comment: @Asperi Yes we are using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SwiftUI 1.0 / SceneDelegate**

You do the same but in your SceneDelegate, following callback:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
        print("Incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
        let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
            guard error == nil else{
                print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            }
        }
}
```

**SwiftUI 2.0 / WindowGroup**

With SwiftUI 2.0 life-cycle you need to use instead `.onContinueUserActivity`, like

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
     .onContinueUserActivity(<your_activity_type_here>) { userActivity in
         if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
              print("Incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
              let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
                    guard error == nil else{
                         print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                         return
                    }
                    if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                         self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
                    }
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of argument should replace <your_activity_type_here> I'm not quite sure

Comment: @Asperi I have the same question as TJ--what do I put in the argument list?

Comment: It is String, any of supported NSUserActivityTypes you declared as supported in you Info.plist. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/task_management/implementing_handoff_in_your_app#3112023

Comment: @Asperi I've done this and the code still is never run! Where and how in the scenedelegate should this code be placed

Comment: @Asperi I did that but the code still doesn't run...where and how in the scenedelegate should this code be placed?

Comment: In SwifUI 2.0 life-cycle there is no SceneDelegate. Do you use UIKit life-cycle? Do you create window via WindowGroup or SceneDelegate?

Comment: @Asperi I am using SceneDelegate, not WindowGroup because I made the app before SwiftUI2 was released

Answer (score 2):

**SwiftUI 2.0 / @main App**
For the new SwiftUI 2.0 you can make an app only using SwiftUI. This means you don't use AppDelegate or SceneDelegate. You then have to use .onOpenURL to get any action called when you click on your link. I am usling this for Firebase Dynamic Links.

```
WindowGroup {
  ContentView()
    .onOpenURL { url in
      // handle the URL that must be opened
      let incomingURL = url
      print("Incoming URL is: \(incomingURL)")
      let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
          guard error == nil else {
             print("Error found!: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
          }
          if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
             self.handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
          }
       }
       if linkHandled{
          print("Link Handled")
          return
       }else{
          print("NO linkHandled")
          return
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Configuring Firebase Dynamic Links on iOS has several steps that must be followed. So, I recommend referring to the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive). Additionally, there is a Firecasts series that walks through all of the steps [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkmQ4uzrIuX-AJssEIIIKi9).

I followed the Firecasts series, but my setup is slightly different; so, I ran into a couple of issues. First, I am using a custom domain. Second, I'm using SwiftUI. I'll just address the issues that I had, so please refer to the full Firecasts series for all of the gruesome details.

### SwiftUI 2.0

There are two different types of links that your app needs to handle. First, your app needs to handle links when your app is already installed (i.e. `https://app.yourcustomdomain.com/...`). Second, your app needs to handle links copied into the clipboard before your app was installed (i.e. `com.your.bundle.id://google/link/...`).

Also, you probably want to handle links originating from a web browser (Safari). In my case, I process a link from a QR code scan. Apparently NFC tag scan links also originate from Safari, but I can't confirm this.

After some trial and error, I found a way to handle all of these concerns with SwiftUI; it's unclear if this is the officially recommended approach, so proceed with caution.

First, use `onOpenURL(perform:)` and `.onContinueUserActivity(_,perform:)`:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .onContinueUserActivity(NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb, perform: onWebBrowserActivity)
            .onOpenURL(perform: onOpenURL)
    }
}
```

Second, define the `onContinueUserActivity` handler:

```
// Handles links originating from the web browser
func onWebBrowserActivity(_ userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
        return
    }
    onOpenURL(url)
}
```

Third, define the `onOpenURL` handler:

```
func onOpenURL(_ url: URL) {
    let dynamicLinks = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()
    if dynamicLinks.shouldHandleDynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url),
       let dynamicLink = dynamicLinks.dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
        handle(dynamicLink: dynamicLink)
    } else {
        handleUniversalLink(url: url)
    }
}
```

Both types of links mentioned above are passed into the onOpenURL handler, so this if statement handles the two cases.

Finally, (as others have mentioned) handle universal links:

```
func handleUniversalLink(url: URL) {
    let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(url) { dynamicLink, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Could not follow the dynamic link \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
            self.handle(dynamicLink: dynamicLink)
        }
    }
    if linkHandled {
        print("Link handled")
    } else {
        print("Link not handled")
    }
}
```

### Custom Domain

I had to follow the custom domain setup instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains). Specifically, I had to set up Firebase Hosting, which requires adding an `A` DNS record (In addition to setting up a `TXT` DNS record for the Dynamic Links URL Prefix setup). Also, I had to specify the custom domain in my `Info.plist`

```
   <key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
   <array>
           <string>https://app.yourcustomdomain.com</string>
   </array>
```