# IOS Universal Link can not be detected in delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm currently testing universal link on my app. I have uploaded apple-app-site-association, edit my app's entitlements file.  The app can be opened when I click the link(say: domain.com/test/id12345) from the Note.

However, it only opens the app, but from the app itself. the delegate method to capture the info is not be called.

the project is a SwiftUI project with iOS 13,  with life cycle of UIKit App Delegate.

Under AppDelegate.swift:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
  
      print("Test: this is never called:\(userActivity)")
      
      guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
        let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
          return false
      }
      return false
    }
```

Is anybody know how to detect the universal link clicked? How should I debug it, the link does open the app but I can't handle the rest.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63940149/12299030?

Comment: This comment helped me a lot with the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490006/5093900

Answer (score 2):

If your application supports multiwindows or you didn't destroy SceneDelegate you need to implement this method in SceneDelegate

```
// SceneDelegate.swift

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    _ = LoginManager.shared.application(.shared, open: URLContexts.first?.url)
}
```